# Should I keep attic gable windows open for ventilation?

Tags: attic, ventilation

Our attic only has a ridge vent (no soffits).  It also has two windows on either end.  It was recommended that we keep them open to help ventilate the attic.

1. Is this a good recommendation?  Should we have them open year round?  (Mid-Atlantic location)
2. If so, how do I account for rain?  I'd prefer to not have to remember to close them whenever it is going to rain.

Answer (score 1):

Attics should remain ventilated, even in winter. Your gable windows should add important circulation to the airflow path. Ideally air is scavenged from all parts of the attic.

Typically there are louvered vents on gables, not windows. You'll need to look into some sort of add-on louver or awning, or replace the windows with something more appropriate.

Comment: Got it.  So if I add garble vents, those would be a better solution that the windows?  Should they also be on opposite ends of the attic or is one enough?

Comment: How much air flows through an empty beer bottle? (Not much at all.) It needs an in door and an out door. In the case of an attic, the ideal is in at the bottom and out at the top.

Comment: The windows are fine, though you don't say what type they are. Single- or double-hung windows offer half the area than a full louver would, so....

Comment: They are double hung, but the screen is only on the bottom portion of both.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a ridge vent, opening or closing the windows won't make *too much* difference, but I'd keep them open, at least during the summer.

To keep the rain out, you can use a louvered window cover, like this. And make sure there's a screen behind it to keep out bugs, rodents, bats and other critters.

[image: louvered vent]

Comment: Very little air exchange occurs beyond a few inches from the ridge without a secondary portal.